# Чтение и запись файл

Tags: c#, файлы

Всем доброго дня. Подскажите пожалуйста.
Задача:

Есть файл с каким то расширение (в данном случаи XPS)

1. Прочитать данные с файла
2. Создать файл с ТАКИМ ЖЕ названием в формате .txt
3. Записать в .txt данные из .XPS

Вопрос:

1. Можно как-то сделать выбор файла в папке по расширению файла т.е. его название всегда разное ?
2. Как скопировать название файла ?

```
namespace CopyTextFile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string FileOld = @"C:\Users\nik88\OneDrive\Desktop\1\1.xps";
        string FileNew = @"C:\Users\nik88\OneDrive\Desktop\1\2.txt";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(FileOld, true))
            {
                using StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(FileNew, false);
                write.WriteLine(read.ReadToEnd());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) OpenFileDialog & SaveFileDialog. 2) string old = "bla"; string new = old; //<-- copy

Comment: Смотрите классы [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-7.0), [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0), [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-7.0) - они содержат всё необходимое для работы с файлами.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо) решил вот так.

```
namespace CopyTextFile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fileContent = string.Empty;
            var filePath = string.Empty;
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\nik88\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\1";


                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //Get the path of specified file
                    filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    //Read the contents of the file into a stream
                    var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();


                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        // Получить название файла без расширения
                        string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
                        // Создать новое имя файла с другим расширением
                        string newFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".txt");

                        using StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(newFilePath, false);
                        write.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());


                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```